# how to create filters in rmarkdown and make dashboard built with rmarkdown interactive

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

i created a dashboard using rmarkdown. i cound not create a filter to make the graphs respond to the input selection pane so that it can be interactive. i need help to make the graphs respond to drop down input for Program, college, department. i also need help to create drillout for my graphs

i tried created a dashboard in rmarkdown using the code below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(openintro)
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
```

```{r}
dat<-read.csv("C://Users//Head-SoftwareUn//Desktop//Yinka//accreditation.csv")
Select = c("PROGRAMME", "COL", "DEPT ")    
```


```{r}
filtered_dat <- reactive({
  dat %>%
    filter(PROGRAMME %in% input$PROGRAMME)
})    
```   

```{r} 
mycolors<-c("blue","yellow","darkgreen","darkorange")    
```      

Program page
=======================
column {.sidebar data-width=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------    

```{r}
 selectInput("my_dropdown", "PROGRAM:", 
              choice= c("-Select Program-",unique(dat$PROGRAMME)))
 selectInput("my_dropdown", "COLLEGE:", 
              choices = c("-Select College-",unique(dat$COL)))
 selectInput("my_dropdown", "DEPARTMENT:", 
              choices = c("-Select Department-",unique(dat$DEPT)))    
```   

### My Dashboard
```{r} 
valueBox(length(dat$PROGRAMME), subtitle="my dashboard")    
```    

Column {data-width=450}
------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
table_dat <- table(dat$ACCREDITATION.STATUS)
p2<-plot_ly(labels = names(table_dat), values = table_dat, type = "pie", hole= 0.4,)
p2    
```    
    
### NUC Next Visit

```{r}
      


```



Row {data-width=500}
------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart C

```{r}
grouped_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(ACCREDITATION.YEARS, ACCREDITATION.STATUS) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
plot_ly(grouped_dat, x = ~ACCREDITATION.YEARS, y = ~count, color = ~ACCREDITATION.STATUS, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(barmode = "group", xaxis= list(title="Accreditatition Years"),yaxis= list(title= 'Count'))    
```    

Row {data-width=500}
------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart D

```{r}
dat1 <- dat %>%
  group_by( ACCREDITATION.STATUS,ACCREDITATION.YEARS) %>%
  summarize(Percent = n() / nrow(dat))
plot <- plot_ly(dat1, x = ~ACCREDITATION.YEARS, y = ~Percent, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
plot <- plot %>% layout(title = "Percentage Line Graph", xaxis = list(title = "Accreditation Years"), yaxis = list(title = "Percent"))
plot

piv<-data.frame(dat$ACCREDITATION.YEARS,dat$ACCREDITATION.STATUS)
piv
```    

# Year page
   
Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```


Column {data-width=250}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart D

```{r}

```
````

i am expecting my graphs to respond to the dropdown input from Program, college, department. i also want a drillout for my graphs

Comment: You create `filtered_dat` as a reactive, but you don't ever use that reactive data frame in a plot.  To make the plot reactive, you would have to use your reactive data frame as the input data.

Comment: how will i use it, pls help with illustration of my code. i tried using it but its giving me error

Comment: Since it's reactive you would have to use `filtered_dat()` (with the trailing parentheses) to access the data.

Comment: Without your data, we can't make the app work.

Comment: thanks it work but still having issue in making the plot in the second page interactive.

Comment: If you can post your data, we may be able to help more. Otherwise it will be difficult.